# Reliability of videoView in Android

Tags: android, video

I got a problem when using videoView to play progressive streaming mp4 videos. Sometimes, when I scrub through the video, the view does not change accordingly and just hang there. It's strange because the time  on the videoView is still running which mean the player is running.
I test this on an Android 2.2 device.  Is this problem caused by videoView ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since android emulator plays .mp4 and .3gpp format videos and the android's video view is not that much good to play a video without pixcelet or hanging it. But if you try to run the same application on an android phone the video will play fine without picxeleting and without being hang. I too faced the same problem earlier with emulator but when I ran the code on android phone it worked great.

Comment: Yup, i've never been able to get VideoView to work on emulator on my machine. One more reason to do all of my development work on a read device.

Comment: Ya if you are doing your development work on a read device it is well and good.

Comment: This problem still exists when I test my app on the real phone

Comment: Then it might be because of bad quality of video you are trying to play.